Selenium get element text after click event
Most modern website have dynamic elements where a click event makes an AJAX call and replaces all or usually part of a webpage. The response  can be tracked using the network tab in Developer tools
How do you do this in Selenium?
In python I thought about grabbing the element text again after the click but it's not updating
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

ChromeDriverPath64 = "D:/Software/chromedriver_126-win64/chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = Service(executable_path="D:/Software/chromedriver_126-win64/chromedriver.exe")

options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"


try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
    driver.get("https://example.com/")
    MyClasss = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "MyClass")
    for el in MyClasss:
        elTxt = el.text
        if "wanted" in elTxt.lower():
            el.click()

            MyClass = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "MyClass")
            for el1 in MyClass:
                el1Txt = el1.text
                if "wanted" in el1Txt.lower():
                    print(el1Txt)

    driver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

There is a lot of conflicting information on how to get AJAX request with Selenium from what I've tried  most seems outdated

By "How do you do this in Selenium?" do you mean, how do you track the AJAX request like you do in the Network tab?

If you're intending to utilize waits to ensure that the page is fully loaded after a click - it differs by framework, but you can see how GitLab does this

TBH I would like to simplest way of grabbing the new element text after it has been updated I don't mind if this is the AJAX response or DOM element. I realize there needs to be a delay after the click currently I'm stepping through the code and can see it change

this is what webdriverwaits are designed for:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

sometimes selenium runs faster then code in JavaScript - and it needs wait for result. If you expect new value then you can run loop which get value from button and compare with previous value - if it different then you can exit loop.

BTW: there is good rule to use CamelCaseNames only for classes (like class Chrome, class Service), and lower_case_names for variables and functions - e.g. chrome_driver_path_64, my_class, el_txt, etc. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

I figured this out after el.click() el1.text didn't change however links = el1.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a") got what I needed. Thanx for  your advise
